# Other multi value optimisation using brute force search?

Tags: search, optimization, scipy, maximize, maximum-profit-problem

I've 6 list of company possible orders (a,b,c,d,e,f) in dollars.The price changes every week (13 weeks) as below.

```
a1_list = [1075000, 1075000, 1072500, 1072500, 1070000, 1070000, 1050000, 1535000, 1535000, 1015000, 1015000, 1000000, 1000000]

b1_list = [1275000, 1275000, 1278000, 1278000, 1242000, 1242000, 1266000, 1806000, 1806000, 1191000, 1191000, 1191000, 1191000]

c1_list = [1530000, 1530000, 1822500, 1822500, 1813500, 1813500, 1804500, 1773000, 1773000, 1746000, 1746000, 1710000, 1710000]

d1_list = [1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 960000, 960000, 960000, 960000,
 960000, 960000]

e1_list = [2436000, 2436000, 2905000, 2905000, 2877000, 2877000, 2849000, 2814000, 2814000, 2779000, 2779000, 2730000, 2730000]

f1_list = [1881000, 1881000, 1890000, 1890000, 1863000, 1863000, 1854000, 1822500, 1822500, 1804500, 1804500, 1786500, 1786500]
```

I can only choose 1 order from a company every time. That is, if I choose the the order for 1st week to be comp A, then company B, C, D, E and F must not be on week1.  Every number in the list correspond to a particular week.

For example, for company A order, the price in week 1 and 2 will be 1075000. If the order is not made in week 1 or 2, but made in week 3 and 4, the price will be 1072500.

This is sort of an optimisation problem.

I wrote a manual calculation to calculate the best combination that give me the best profit.

Below are my codes:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

price = np.array([
    [430,   425,    340,    402,    348,    418],
    [429,   426,    405,    402,    415,    420],
    [428,   414,    403,    402,    411,    414],
    [420,   422,    401,    402,    407,    412],
    [614,   602,    394,    384,    402,    405],
    [406,   397,    388,    384,    397,    401],
    [400,   397,    380,    384,    390,    397],
    ])

a1Q = 2500
a2Q = 4000
b1Q = 3000
b2Q = 3500
c1Q = 4500
c2Q = 5500
c3Q = 4000
d1Q = 2500
d2Q = 4000
e1Q = 7000
e2Q = 2000
f1Q = 4500
f2Q = 1000
 

a1_price = price[:,0]*a1Q
a2_price = price[:,0]*a2Q
b1_price = price[:,1]*b1Q
b2_price = price[:,1]*b2Q
c1_price = price[:,2]*c1Q
c2_price = price[:,2]*c2Q
c3_price = price[:,2]*c3Q
d1_price = price[:,3]*d1Q
d2_price = price[:,3]*d2Q
e1_price = price[:,4]*e1Q
e2_price = price[:,4]*e2Q
f1_price = price[:,5]*f1Q
f2_price = price[:,5]*f2Q


a1_list = [a1_price[0]]*2 + [a1_price[1]]*2 + [a1_price[2]]*2 + [a1_price[3]] + [a1_price[4]]*2 + [a1_price[5]]*2 + [a1_price[6]]*2
a2_list = [a2_price[0]]*2 + [a2_price[1]]*2 + [a2_price[2]]*2 + [a2_price[3]] + [a2_price[4]]*2 + [a2_price[5]]*2 + [a2_price[6]]*2
b1_list = [b1_price[0]]*2 + [b1_price[1]]*2 + [b1_price[2]]*2 + [b1_price[3]] + [b1_price[4]]*2 + [b1_price[5]]*2 + [b1_price[6]]*2
b2_list = [b2_price[0]]*2 + [b2_price[1]]*2 + [b2_price[2]]*2 + [b2_price[3]] + [b2_price[4]]*2 + [b2_price[5]]*2 + [b2_price[6]]*2
c1_list = [c1_price[0]]*2 + [c1_price[1]]*2 + [c1_price[2]]*2 + [c1_price[3]] + [c1_price[4]]*2 + [c1_price[5]]*2 + [c1_price[6]]*2
c2_list = [c2_price[0]]*2 + [c2_price[1]]*2 + [c2_price[2]]*2 + [c2_price[3]] + [c2_price[4]]*2 + [c2_price[5]]*2 + [c2_price[6]]*2
c3_list = [c3_price[0]]*2 + [c3_price[1]]*2 + [c3_price[2]]*2 + [c3_price[3]] + [c3_price[4]]*2 + [c3_price[5]]*2 + [c3_price[6]]*2
d1_list = [d1_price[0]]*2 + [d1_price[1]]*2 + [d1_price[2]]*2 + [d1_price[3]] + [d1_price[4]]*2 + [d1_price[5]]*2 + [d1_price[6]]*2
d2_list = [d2_price[0]]*2 + [d2_price[1]]*2 + [d2_price[2]]*2 + [d2_price[3]] + [d2_price[4]]*2 + [d2_price[5]]*2 + [d2_price[6]]*2
e1_list = [e1_price[0]]*2 + [e1_price[1]]*2 + [e1_price[2]]*2 + [e1_price[3]] + [e1_price[4]]*2 + [e1_price[5]]*2 + [e1_price[6]]*2
e2_list = [e2_price[0]]*2 + [e2_price[1]]*2 + [e2_price[2]]*2 + [e2_price[3]] + [e2_price[4]]*2 + [e2_price[5]]*2 + [e2_price[6]]*2
f1_list = [f1_price[0]]*2 + [f1_price[1]]*2 + [f1_price[2]]*2 + [f1_price[3]] + [f1_price[4]]*2 + [f1_price[5]]*2 + [f1_price[6]]*2
f2_list = [f2_price[0]]*2 + [f2_price[1]]*2 + [f2_price[2]]*2 + [f2_price[3]] + [f2_price[4]]*2 + [f2_price[5]]*2 + [f2_price[6]]*2

best = 0
ind_a1,ind_b1,ind_c1,ind_d1,ind_e1,ind_f1 = 0,0,0,0,0,0

for a1 in a1_list:
    # print(f'A: {ind_a}')
    # ind_a+=1
    ind_b1 = 0
    # ind_c=0
    for b1 in b1_list:
        
        if ind_b1 != ind_a1:
            
            # print(ind_b)
            # total = a + b
            ind_c1 = 0
            
            for c1 in c1_list:
                
                if ind_c1 != ind_a1 and ind_c1 != ind_b1:
                    
                    
                    ind_d1 = 0
                    
                    for d1 in d1_list:
                        
                        if ind_d1 != ind_a1 \
                            and ind_d1 != ind_b1 \
                                and ind_d1!= ind_c1:
                            
                            ind_e1 = 0                               
                            
                            for e1 in e1_list:
                                
                                if ind_e1 != ind_a1 \
                                    and ind_e1 != ind_b1 \
                                        and ind_e1!= ind_c1 \
                                            and ind_e1!= ind_d1:
                                    
                                    ind_f1 = 0
                                    
                                    for f1 in f1_list:
                                        
                                        if ind_f1 != ind_a1 \
                                            and ind_f1 != ind_b1 \
                                                and ind_f1!= ind_c1 \
                                                    and ind_f1!= ind_d1 \
                                                        and ind_f1!= ind_e1:
                                    
                                            total = a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + e1 + f1
                        
                                            if total >best:
                                                best = total
                                                print(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1, ind_a1,ind_b1,ind_c1,ind_d1,ind_e1,ind_f1)
                                                print(best)
                                                
                                        ind_f1 +=1
                                ind_e1 +=1
                        ind_d1 += 1
                ind_c1+=1            
        ind_b1+=1
    ind_a1+=1
```

I'm wondering if there's a simpler and cleaner way to solve this problem, or to use built in scipy optimization functions like scipy.optimize.minimize or scipy.optimize.brute?

This is actually a portion of a huge problem optimisation function that I'm solving.

Just to give you an idea (but may be irrelevant to this question), below are some plot. I'm trying to maximize the revenue.
[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is best solved using munkres algorithm (or otherwise known as the Hungarian algorithm).

To get an idea how this algorithm works,

you can watch the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQ5MsiGaDY8

To do it in Python, first install munkres library.

```
pip install munkres
```

You can refer here for more information.

http://software.clapper.org/munkres/

Below is my sample code to solve this problem without looping 6 billion+ times (13 variables) --> O(n!). With munkres algorithm, it's O(n^3). Apparently, there're tricks to optimized the values through some mathematical matrix reduction technique. The video above will give you some idea.

```
from munkres import Munkres, print_matrix
import sys

matrix = [
    a1_list,
    b1_list,
    c1_list,
    d1_list,
    e1_list,
    f1_list,
    a2_list,
    b2_list,
    c2_list,
    d2_list,
    e2_list,
    f2_list,
    c3_list,
          ]

cost_matrix = []
for row in matrix:
    cost_row = []
    for col in row:
        cost_row += [sys.maxsize - col]
    cost_matrix += [cost_row]

m = Munkres()
indexes = m.compute(cost_matrix)
print_matrix(matrix, msg='Highest profit through this matrix:')
total = 0
for row, column in indexes:
    value = matrix[row][column]
    total += value
    print(f'({row}, {column}) -> {value}')

print(f'total profit={total}')
```

You'll get result as below.

```
Highest profit through this matrix:
[1575000, 1575000, 1072500, 1072500, 1070000, 1070000, 1050000, 1035000, 1035000, 1015000, 1015000, 1000000, 1000000]
[1275000, 1275000, 1278000, 1278000, 1242000, 1242000, 1266000, 1806000, 1806000, 1191000, 1191000, 1191000, 1191000]
[1530000, 1530000, 1822500, 1822500, 1813500, 1813500, 1804500, 1773000, 1773000, 1746000, 1746000, 1710000, 1710000]
[1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000, 1005000,  960000,  960000,  960000,  960000,  960000,  960000]
[2436000, 2436000, 2905000, 2905000, 2877000, 2877000, 2849000, 2814000, 2814000, 2779000, 2779000, 2730000, 2730000]
[1881000, 1881000, 1890000, 1890000, 1863000, 1863000, 1854000, 1822500, 1822500, 1804500, 1804500, 1786500, 1786500]
[2520000, 2520000, 1716000, 1716000, 1712000, 1712000, 1680000, 1656000, 1656000, 1624000, 1624000, 1600000, 1600000]
[1487500, 1487500, 1491000, 1491000, 1449000, 1449000, 1477000, 2107000, 2107000, 1389500, 1389500, 1389500, 1389500]
[1870000, 1870000, 2227500, 2227500, 2216500, 2216500, 2205500, 2167000, 2167000, 2134000, 2134000, 2090000, 2090000]
[1608000, 1608000, 1608000, 1608000, 1608000, 1608000, 1608000, 1536000, 1536000, 1536000, 1536000, 1536000, 1536000]
(0, 0) -> 1575000
(1, 7) -> 1806000
(2, 4) -> 1813500
(3, 12) -> 960000
(4, 3) -> 2905000
(5, 2) -> 1890000
(6, 1) -> 2520000
(7, 8) -> 2107000
(8, 5) -> 2216500
(9, 6) -> 1608000
total profit=19401000
```